# How can I toggle image source on checkbox click?

Tags: reactjs

I have a checkbox and two images. When the checkbox is not checked, I want to show the first image. But when the checkbox is checked, I want to display another image.
I am new to React and I am not sure how to achieve this. Anybody can help?

Comment: Please show your effort and any related code. Your question doesn't meet minimum standards as it is.

Comment: You can google it, you will find related solutions